# SOQL problem with redundant white space

Tags: soql, dynamic-soql

My record has an 'Adress' string field and the value like this:

```
'SNBR - 772178 SNME SSTTAB, SCITY SSTATE  SZIP_'
```

Note that it has 2 whitespaces between 'SSTATE' and 'SZIP_'. However, this field when being shown on salesforce has reduced redundant whitespace. So when I copy this string and query again (using the LIKE operator), it doesn't return the value.

Here is my query:

```
Select Id, Address__c From sObject__c 
 WHERE Adress LIKE 'SNBR - 772178 SNME SSTTAB, SCITY SSTATE SZIP_'

// Note: In this query, there is only 1 whitespace between 'SSTATE' and 'SZIP_'.
```

The problem is that I have thousands of records and cannot manually check every single one of them. How could I write SOQL to query them without worrying about this mistake? Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: Please could you provide the SOQL you're currently using? The ugly solution is of course to use OR over the whole WHERE - fit for use only for a one-off query. But I guess you have the same problem with all the blanks in your string?! And not even know how many blanks there are?!

Comment: I have added SOQL in the post, @FelixvanHove

Comment: The brute force solution would be to simply replace all the double spaces before you start querying. In case you're not planning to do that, are you planning to use this query in apex? In that case it would be easy to resolve with dynamic soql. If not then you'll have to adjust the query string manually. The easiest way would probably be to add a % sign after the last space, although that would technically match anything.

Comment: Thanks, @Kasper. I do plan to use this query in apex but I think I must replace all double spaces for future development. Because when users input their address, the duplicate spaces could appear anywhere in the string not only in the last space. So maybe I could create a trigger to remove duplicate space before adding records.

Comment: @TuấnTrầnquốc That sounds like a good plan. Addresses are difficult to deal with in my experience. There are generally many different ways to write them down and this means that it is hard to properly match them with queries.